# How to store a json data securely in phonegap android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am developing an android app in phonegap. I have to store a json data that should be secured. The json contains authentication keys and tokens so it should not expose. So I cant store it to any kind of javascript local storages. Is there any other way to save data securely ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use android Shared preference, you can set it by plugin. 
Here are the steps :

1 In your javascript add this

```
function storeJSON(JSON_String){

      cordova.exec(function() {
           //CALLBACK SUCCESS
        }, function(error) {
           //ERROR CALLBACK                    
        }, "YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS", [JSON_String,"SET"]);
}

function getJSON(){

      cordova.exec(function(Json) {
           //CALLBACK SUCCESS
           alert(Json);
        }, function(error) {
           //ERROR CALLBACK                    
        }, "YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS", ["","GET"]);
}
```

2 Create Java class YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS.  [Download](http://codeshare.io/J1R4b)

3 In config.xml add this

```
<feature name="YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS">
     <param name="android-package" value="yourpackage.YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Hi manu.. thanks for ur answer, I want to know that where it going to store and how can I erase it after my usage?

Comment: It stores in application file system. If you need to delete it, just pass a null value to storeJSON() function. simply :)

Answer (score 0):

Use native storage methods like   sqlite DB thats better,
check https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin  - **Sqlite plugin for Android**